# Location based on correct map center for Google Place Service Nearby Search results

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

This code successfully takes a localStorage place id variable passed from an autocomplete field (can click "Map It" and enter a place in the pop up that appears, at roadtripsharing.com to test), and creates a marker, info window, and circle. I included a default location {lat: 39, lng: -105} in case users accessed the page directly without any localStorage use. However, even when I go from the home page and store something in local storage, the places that come up (in this case ATM machines) are all centered around Colorado Springs, USA, which is the {lat: 39, lng: -105}.

I believe at the point of declaring

```
var request = {
        location: mapit.getCenter(),
        radius: 5000,
        //  query: 'atm'
        types: ['atm']
      };
```

mapit.getCenter() should be results[0].geometry.location (the marker location based on the localStorage Place ID passed from the home page). How to make the Place Service Nearby Search result use this as the location instead of always {lat: 39, lng: -105}?

```
function initMapIt() {    
  var mapit = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapitmap'), {
      center: {lat: 39, lng: -105},
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });  
  var rtscircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        radius:document.getElementById("rtsfader").value*1609.34, 
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeColor: "blue",
          strokeOpacity: 0.9,
        fillColor: "red",
        fillOpacity: 0.15,
          clickable: false,
        map: mapit
        });
  if (localStorage.placetopass !== null){
    var rtsgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var newplace = localStorage.getItem('placetopass');
    rtsgeocoder.geocode({'placeId': newplace}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        mapit.setZoom(11);
        mapit.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var rtsmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: mapit,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        var rtsinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        rtsinfowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address+'<p><a href="http://roadtripsharing.com/rate-place">Rate this place?</a></p>');
        rtsinfowindow.open(mapit, rtsmarker);
        rtsmarker.addListener('click', function() {
          rtsinfowindow.open(mapit, rtsmarker);
        });
        rtscircle.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        jQuery("#rtsfader").change(function(){
          rtscircle.setRadius(document.getElementById("rtsfader").value*1609.34);
        });
      }                           
         else {
        rtscircle.setCenter({lat: 39, lng: -105});   
      }
    } else {
      rtscircle.setCenter({lat: 39, lng: -105});
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("rts-aahs").play();
  }
  var request = {
    location: mapit.getCenter(),
    radius: 5000,
    //  query: 'atm'
    types: ['atm']
  };
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(mapit);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
      console.log(results[i]);
    }
  }
  else
      alert("Status not OK");
}

function createMarker(place) {
    // alert("createMarker function");
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: mapit,
    position:  place.geometry.location
  });
  console.log(marker);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(mapit, this);
  });
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `mapit.getCenter()` *before* you call `mapit.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location)`.  This happens because the you update the map center in the callback of `rtsgeocoder.geocode(...)`, but you don't wait for that to run before continuing with doing the `nearbySearch`.  You can verify this easily by adding a couple of `console.log` calls just before the `getCenter`/`setCenter` calls and observing the order they happen.

To fix this, you could try one of these approaches:

1. wait for up to some deadline (e.g. 2 seconds) for `rtsgeocoder.geocode` to run its callback before calling `getCenter` (and the `nearbySearch` based on it).  This isn't very robust, for example a slow network link could mean it takes more than 2 seconds, and in the meantime you have no markers to show your user.
2. call `nearbySearch` from your `rtsgeocoder.geocode` callback as well as immediately — or even every time the map center is changed.  Because adding lots of markers to a map can consume memory and slow down the page you'll probably want to remove the old markers when you get the new ones.  For example by keeping an array of of markers added by your `createMarker` function and call `marker.setMap(null)` on each of them.

I think option 2 is usually the better choice.

Comment: Thanks, calling nearbySearch from rtsgeocoder.geocode after the center change worked.